# hover popup overlapping table fields with large text react

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, html-table

I am working on a react app where I have a table and one of my column has really large text value ,so in order to show that value I am using a hover popup to show the full text on hovering over the column value but when I hover over it,it overlaps the other columns as it show the whole text in 1 straight line.

Here's the table row and truncate function:

```
truncate = (str, n) => (str.length > n ? `${str.substr(0, n - 1)}...` : str);

<Table.Cell data-title={message.job_data}>
                    {this.truncate(message.job_data,50)}
                  </Table.Cell>
```

Here's the css of data-title:

```
 [data-title] {
      font-size: 14px;
      position: relative;
      cursor: help;
  }
    
  [data-title]:hover::before {
      content: attr(data-title);
    opacity: 1;
      position: absolute;
    margin-top:33px;
      padding: 10px;
      background: #000;
      color: #fff;
      font-size: 14px;
    width:300px;
      white-space: wrap;
    z-index: 9;
  }
  [data-title]:hover::after {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
    opacity: 1;
      bottom: -12px;
      left: 8px;
      border: 8px solid transparent;    
      border-bottom: 8px solid #000;
  }
```

I want to show the column text in multiple lines and not a straight line overlapping all the other columns.

Attaching a screenshot of my error:

[image]

As you can see in the message column,the text is very long and it is showing it horizontally overlapping all the columns.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As the text you try to break doesn't have any white-space in it, only way I can think of doing this in CSS is by `word-break: break-word;`

```css
[data-title]:hover::before {
    content: attr(data-title);
    opacity: 1;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top:33px;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 14px;
    width:300px;
    word-break: break-word;
    z-index:9;
  }
```

Comment: It was great :)

Comment: Thanks,it helped.Can you please remove the image? data is kinda confedencial

Comment: Note that you will also need to delete the image from imgur where it was uploaded, else the confidential data will be forever reachable from the edit history of this question. Perhaps a moderator can help with that...